# Unable to configure zoho invoice/books app in my admin account

Tags: configuration, crm, invoice, zoho

Today, I am facing issue to configure zoho invoice and books app

Note : **Zoho Service Communication (ZSC) Key Generated** by following [this](https://www.zoho.com/recruit/help/help-client-generate-ZSC-key.html) article

What i did :

- Login in CRM
- Click Setup
- Apps & Add-ons
- Click on Zoho Invoice/Zoho Books
- Two buttons display configure Zoho invoce and configure Zoho books
- After select any of them asking for email address and ZSC key

Here is the issue, when i put my email and zsc key, it show the error **Internal Process Error**

Please help me i m new in zoho, guide me if something miss-configured.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Zoho CRM app, enter the ZSC Key of Zoho Invoice or Zoho Books in the integration setup page. To generate the ZSC Key of Zoho Invoice/Zoho Books, kindly follow the steps mentioned below.

- Login to either [Zoho Invoice](https://invoice.zoho.com)/[Zoho Books](https://books.zoho.com).
- Go to Integrations by clicking Settings icon in the top right corner.
- Click on 'Zoho Invoice ZSC key' or 'Zoho Books ZSC Key'
- If there is no key, click on 'Generate Now'.
- Then copy the key and email address and enter the same in Zoho CRM account.

Then you can configure the Contacts sync and Products sync between Zoho CRM and Zoho Books/Zoho Invoice. Kindly refer this [link](https://www.zoho.com/books/help/integrations/crm-integration.html) to more details.